# Making pretty json string with python's json

Tags: python, json

I am using python's `json` to produce a json file and cannot manage to format it the way I want.

What I have is a dictionary with some keys, and each key has a list of numbers attached to it:

```
out = {"a": [1,2,3], "b": [4,5,6]}
```

What I want to do is produce a JSON string where each list is in its own line, like so:

```
{
    "a": [1,2,3],
    "b": [4,5,6]
}
```

However, I can only get

```
>>> json.dumps(out)
'{"a": [1, 2, 3], "b": [4, 5, 6]}'
```

which has no new lines, or

```
>>> print json.dumps(out, indent=2)
{
  "a": [
    1, 
    2, 
    3
  ], 
  "b": [
    4, 
    5, 
    6
  ]
}
```

which has waaay to many. Is there a simply way to produce the string I want? I can do it manually, of course, but I am wondering if it is possible with `json` alone...

Comment: Nope, that was never the goal of the python `json` module. Why do you want to control the format so specifically? JSON parsers don't care.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks for the quick answer. Do you know of any other module that can do what I want?

Comment: Nope, I'm not aware of any code that gives you this much control over the JSON output produced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that with the `json` module, no. It was never the goal for the module to allow this much control over the output.

The `indent` option is only meant to aid debugging. JSON parsers don't care about how much whitespace is used in-between elements.

Comment: I understand that, yes. However, since JSON is still a human-readable serialization, I thought maybe there is some way. Oh well.